# Remote debugging in Android Chrome fails (since updated in March 2013)

Tags: android, google-chrome, remote-debugging

I'm facing an issue to remote debugging Chrome in android (updated in March 2013)?

I've got to debug my bug from this latest chrome so I've to pass through this situation.

It was almost perfect to remote debugging my Chrome in Android prior to update it to version 25.0.1364.169

I have 3 devices and I tried to roll back Chrome to version 18.xxx and I'm able to remote debugging with older chrome version.

When I updated to the latest chrome mention above what I got in the console was like this

```
Application Cache Progress event (9 of 208) http://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/static/25.0.1364.169/TimelinePanel.js devtools.html:1
Application Cache Error event: Resource fetch failed (-1) http://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/static/25.0.1364.169/TimelinePanel.js devtools.html:1
Failed to load resource
```

It failed to load TimelinePanel.js

Anyone got the way out from this issue?

Comment: please please raise a bug on http://crbug.com/new and email me so I can get the team on it paulkinlan at google dot com

Comment: I have had it working today live on a show.

Comment: user, any update?  I can't replicate this either.